# Galois extension with Galois group $S_3$

Tags: number-theory, galois-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Let $F/\mathbb{Q}$ be a Galois estension with Galois group $S_3$. We have three $C_2$ in $S_3$ one for each cycle, say $C_{2a}, C_{2b}, C_{2c}$. Take $C_{2a}<S_3$ and be $M$ its fixed field.

Assume  $p\in\mathbb{Z}$ ramifies in $F$.  It is well known that the number of the primes in $M$ above $p$ is equal to the number of double cosets $C_{2a}\backslash S_3 / D_p$ where $D_p$ indicates the decomposition subgroup of $p$.

Now, we can have $D_p \in \lbrace C_{2a}, C_{2b}, C_{2c} \rbrace$. In particualr, when $D_p=C_{2a}$ then $M$ is the decomposition field of $p$. Thus, $p$ totally split in $M$ that is $p\mathcal{O}_M=P_1P_2P_3$, but the number of the double cosets is 2. So, there is a big mistake in my reasonament but I don't understand where.

Comment: Why should we have $pO_M=P_1P_2P_3$? Let $F$ be the splitting field of $x^3-2$. Modulo $p=5$ we have that $x^3-2=(x+2)(x^2+3x+4)$, so in all the cubic intermediate fields $M$ (they are all conjugate) we have $5O_M=P_1P_2$  with one of the ideals being a larger residue class field. In the intermediate field $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{-3})$ the prime $p=5$ is inert, so we are in the $e=1, f=2, g=3$ situation.

Comment: Because we are assuming that the decomposition $D_p^{F/Q}$ group is $C_2$ so in $F$ there are 3 primes above $p$. Now $M$ is supposed to be the decomposition group of $p$ and the extension $M/Q$ is of degree 3. And in the decomposition field of prime a $p$, the ideal generated by $p$ here splits always completely.

Comment: Or in other words, isn't the decomposition subgroup associated to a prime  $\mathfrak{p}$ of $F$, and the decomposition field $M$ is the smallest field with the property that $\mathfrak{p}\cap M$ does not split in the extension $F/M$. It has nothing to do with total splitting, right?

Comment: In the example $F=\Bbb{Q}(\root3\of2,\sqrt{-3})$ we have $D_\mathfrak{p}\simeq C_2$ for all the primes above $5$.

Comment: it is late also here sorry if am slow. But the decomposition field is not charcterized by the fact that is the largest intermediate subfield where $e_p=f_p=1$?

Comment: Only if the extension $F/\Bbb{Q}$ is abelian is there a decomposition group of a rational prime $p$. Otherwise we have conjugate decomposition groups of the distinct conjugate primes above $p$.

Comment: yes, I understand sorry if I have been veeeery slow. It's to late for me & maths!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your reasoning is missing the fact that only in Galois extensions are you given that $e, f, r$ are independent of the prime chosen. So you can have $p = P_1P_2$ (indeed you must, as you note!) Your assumption of regularity is the main issue, but there are plenty of examples where you do not have something **totally** split in the decomposition field, in the case the subextension is Galois this changes, but obviously unless $D_p\trianglelefteq G$ the subextension need not be Galois.

**Note** I spoke earlier on the inertial groups, but the problem with that is that of course this is for local fields. The local information is still useful, as you note that completing or localizing at one of the primes still gives you information, but the splitting information is embedded in the step prior to this when engaging with $D_p$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! So, can we not have $D_p=I_p=C_2$? So does the fact that $C_3$ is normal allow us to find primes $p$ such that $C_3=D_p=I_p$? for example in $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt[3]{7},\zeta_3]$, $p=7$ has this property.

Comment: @user262440 Yes, that's what it boils down to. And that's the beauty of your analysis, if you look at it there's only one place where you make an unjustified assertion, and so you know that's the source of the contradiction.

Comment: It's past midnight here, and I can't think straight, but... Why is the ramification group $I_p$ a normal subgroup of $G$? It is a normal subgroup of $D_p$, sure, because it the kernel of an action of $D_p$, but why normal in $G$?

Comment: Yes i was supposing that it was a little mistake and he referred to $D_p$.

Comment: @jyrkiLahtonen oops, I've been working on things with local fields lately. I'll fix that when I'm not on mobile